# Generic ActionResule<T> in .NET Core doesnot respect the type T

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, oop, polymorphism

In the below example, `GET` method has return type of

```
ActionResult<SomeAltResult>
```

but the return statement returns `OKResult` with an `IEnumerable` of `WeatherForecast` and still it is compiling successfully.

I am not able to understand if I can return anything then what is the point of having generic `ActionResult<T>`, I can use `ActionResult` or `IActionResult`.

Also please help me to understands the `ActionResult<T>` does not inherit any class or interface chain of `OkObjectResult` then how is the polymorphism working here?

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]{
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm","Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };
    
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public ActionResult<SomeAltResult> Get()
    {
        var x = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
    
        return Ok(x);
    }
}

public class SomeAltResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Also please help me to understands the `ActionResult<T>` does not inherit any class or interface chain of `OkObjectResult` then how is the polymorphism working here?

The `ActionResult<T>` class defines [an implicit conversion from any `ActionResult` to `ActionResult<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1.op_implicit#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-actionresult-1-op-implicit(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-actionresult)-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-actionresult((-0))), which explains why it compiles.

Code like this also compiles:

```
ActionResult<SomeAltResult> actionResult = Ok(x);
```

That conversion most likely makes use of [the constructor overload that takes any `ActionResult` as input](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1.-ctor#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-actionresult-1-ctor(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-actionresult)). Notice that it's not constrained on the generic type parameter in any way. Thus, you can use *any* `ActionResult`, including `OkObjectResult`.

> I am not able to understand if I can return anything then what is the point of having generic `ActionResult<T>`, I can use `ActionResult` or `IActionResult`.

It is, indeed, an odd API design. Consider this variation of the OP code:

```
ActionResult<SomeAltResult> actionResult = Ok(x);
SomeAltResult? value = actionResult.Value; // null
return Ok(value);
```

This also compiles, but the web resource now returns an empty result. This happens because `actionResult.Value` returns `null` since it has no value of the type `T`.

I can't explain that API design choice. Such silent failures indicate to me an API design flaw. Code like that shouldn't be allowed to compile without warnings.

The reason that the OP works despite of all this is that the only thing that the ASP.NET framework cares about is whether a Controller Action returns an [IActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult), and the [ExecuteResultAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult.executeresultasync) method doesn't care about generics. It only coverts the `IActionResult` object to an HTTP response, and [at the boundaries, static types don't exist](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2023/10/16/at-the-boundaries-static-types-are-illusory).